# Escape commas in REST API

Tags: plugins, rest-api, api, wp-api

Sending metadata through the REST API like this, is creating multiple entries because of the commas

```
meta: {
plugin_rule_what: 'discount_percentage',
plugin_rule_applies_multiple_options:'product_22119, product_22283',
}
```

However, I need this to be entered as a string with commas in the database.

Is there a way to escape them or otherwise do this?

Comment: You can use back slash to escape characters, like this \,

Comment: You could also send them as an array: `plugin_rule_applies_multiple_options: [ 'product_22119', 'product_22283' ],`